# Adding sign + betwen lines (not math mode)

Tags: alignment

I edited a [function about *vertical*](http://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/tex/A/question/11702.html) mltiplication to achieve **horizontal** placement of the two **multipliers**.

[image: Multiplication with and without the sign + which I need]

I need the sign `+` centered between 6942 and 4628 in black color.I tried with `\begin{align}` but the functions for the `\multiplication` doesn't work .

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp,intcalc}
\begin{document}
    \def\multiplication#1#2{
        \def\answer{\FPmul\temp{#1}{#2}
            \parindent=0pt
            \FPround\temp{\temp}{0}\temp}
        \def\lineFirst{#1.#2}
        \def\linez##1##2##3{
            \intcalcMul{#1}{##2}##3}
        \def\Rule{\rule{1.3cm}{0.3pt}}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1.5cm}
            \begin{flushright}
                \lineFirst \vspace{-3mm}
                \Rule \\
                \def\Z{\phantom{0}}
                \linez{#1}{2}\\
                \linez{#1}{1}{\Z}\\[-8pt]
                \Rule
                \answer
            \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}}
    \multiplication{2314}{12}
    $\; \;$ 
    \multiplication{2314}{12}

\end{document}
```

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Pe80kHb]

Comment: I'm not sure *what* numbers you're multiplying: 2314 by 12 makes 27768, but 6942 comes from nowhere.

Comment: @egreg this line              `\linez{#1}{1}{\Z}\\[-8pt]` was                 `\linez{#1}{3}{\Z}\\[-8pt]`. The second one is wrong. I edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `expl3` for the job. Do you really use a period for denoting multiplication?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\multiplication}{sO{c}mm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \ensuremath{ #3.#4=\int_eval:n { #3 * #4 } }
   }
   {
    \simeon_multiplication:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_b_seq
\seq_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_c_seq
\int_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_step_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \simeon_multiplication:nnn
 {
  % store the second factor in reverse order
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__simeon_multiplication_b_seq { } { #3 }
  \seq_reverse:N \l__simeon_multiplication_b_seq
  % store the partial products with a padding
  \seq_clear:N \l__simeon_multiplication_c_seq
  \int_zero:N \l__simeon_multiplication_step_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_b_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__simeon_multiplication_c_seq
     {
      &\int_eval:n { #2 * ##1 }
      \prg_replicate:nn { \l__simeon_multiplication_step_int } { \__simeon_zero: }
     }
    \int_incr:N \l__simeon_multiplication_step_int
   }
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}r@{}r@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}r@{}}{#2.#3} \\
  \midrule
  \seq_use:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_c_seq { \__simeon_plus: } \\
  \midrule
  & \int_eval:n { #2 * #3 }
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simeon_zero: { \hphantom{0} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simeon_plus:
 {
  \\
  \raisebox{0.6667\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{+\,}
  \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% center align
\multiplication{2314}{12}
\multiplication{9999}{99}
\multiplication{9999}{9999}

\bigskip

% top align
\multiplication[t]{2314}{12}
\multiplication[t]{9999}{99}
\multiplication[t]{9999}{9999}

\bigskip

% bottom align
\multiplication[b]{2314}{12}
\multiplication[b]{9999}{99}
\multiplication[b]{9999}{9999}

\bigskip

% only multiplication
\multiplication*{2314}{12}\par
\multiplication*{9999}{99}\par
\multiplication*{9999}{9999}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version that swaps the numbers for doing the computation, if the first is less than the second. It also works with floating point numbers (the alignment is not perfect, in this case, though, at the moment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx,booktabs,multirow}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\multiplication}{sO{c}mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \sisetup { group-separator = {} }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_do_tl { \num{#3}.\num{#4} }
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \simeon_multiplication_inline:nn { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \simeon_multiplication:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\tl_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_do_tl
\tl_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl
\tl_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl
\seq_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_b_seq
\seq_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_c_seq
\int_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_step_int
\fp_new:N \l__simeon_multiplication_result_fp

\cs_new_protected:Nn \simeon_multiplication_inline:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl { #2 }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl { , } { . }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl { , } { . }
  \ensuremath
   {
    \l__simeon_multiplication_do_tl =
    \num
     {
      \fp_eval:n
       {
        \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl * \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl
       }
     }
   }
 }


\cs_new_protected:Nn \simeon_multiplication:nnn
 {
  % store the second factor in reverse order
  \tl_set:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl { #3 }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl { , } { . }
  \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl { , } { . }
  \fp_set:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_result_fp
   {
    \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl * \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl
   }
  \fp_compare:nTF { \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl > \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl }
   {
    \__simeon_multiplication:nNN { #1 } \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl
   }
   {
    \__simeon_multiplication:nNN { #1 } \l__simeon_multiplication_b_tl \l__simeon_multiplication_a_tl
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simeon_multiplication:nNN
 {
  % find the number of final zeros
  \tl_clear:N \l__simeon_multiplication_zeros_tl
  \__simeon_multiplication_zeros:NN #2 #3
  % remove the decimal separator
  \tl_remove_once:Nn #2 { . }
  \tl_remove_once:Nn #3 { . }
  % store the second factor in reverse order
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__simeon_multiplication_b_seq { } #3
  \seq_reverse:N \l__simeon_multiplication_b_seq
  % store the partial products with a padding
  \seq_clear:N \l__simeon_multiplication_c_seq
  \int_zero:N \l__simeon_multiplication_step_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_b_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__simeon_multiplication_c_seq
     {
      &\int_eval:n { #2 * ##1 }
      \prg_replicate:nn { \l__simeon_multiplication_step_int } { \__simeon_zero: }
     }
    \int_incr:N \l__simeon_multiplication_step_int
   }
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}r@{}r@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}r@{}}{\l__simeon_multiplication_do_tl} \\
  \midrule
  \multirow{\tl_count:N #3}{*}{\raisebox{\depth}{+}\,}
  \seq_use:Nn \l__simeon_multiplication_c_seq { \\ } \\
  \midrule
  & \num{ \fp_use:N \l__simeon_multiplication_result_fp }
    \l__simeon_multiplication_zeros_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simeon_zero: { \hphantom{0} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simeon_plus:
 {
  \\
  \raisebox{0.66667\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{+\,}
  \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simeon_multiplication_zeros:NN
 {
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { . } #1
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpb_seq { . } #2
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 }
    \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 2 }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \fp_eval:n { #1 * #2 } }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { . } \l_tmpb_tl
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__simeon_multiplication_zeros_tl
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { \tl_count:N \l_tmpa_tl - \tl_count:N \l_tmpb_tl } { 0 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% center align
\multiplication{2314}{12}\quad
\multiplication{12}{2314}\quad
\multiplication{9999}{99}\quad
\multiplication{9999}{9999}\quad
\multiplication{23,14}{1,2}\quad
\multiplication{235}{388}\quad
\multiplication{2,35}{38,8}

\bigskip

% top align
\multiplication[t]{2314}{12}\quad
\multiplication[t]{12}{2314}\quad
\multiplication[t]{9999}{99}\quad
\multiplication[t]{9999}{9999}\quad
\multiplication[t]{23,14}{1,2}

\bigskip

% bottom align
\multiplication[b]{2314}{12}\quad
\multiplication[b]{12}{2314}\quad
\multiplication[b]{9999}{99}\quad
\multiplication[b]{9999}{9999}\quad
\multiplication[b]{23,14}{1,2}

\bigskip

% only multiplication
\multiplication*{2314}{12}\par
\multiplication*{12}{2314}\par
\multiplication*{9999}{99}\par
\multiplication*{9999}{9999}\par
\multiplication*{23,14}{1,2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's good but I changed my calculations. I need the second one which is marked in pink, which is a lot simpler for 12yo kids. https://imgur.com/a/IEOWqTL 
 And if it's possible to work with floating points numbers? I knew only I had to replace 2-3 function in my example for this.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov Yes, it's possible. The added version checks for the largest number and works with floating point numbers. A hint about what alignment you expect in the floating point number case is needed.

Comment: Nice. There is something a bit wrong. The result is moved to the right with one char  and there is no zero. 
https://imgur.com/a/XGFyI40
And I think only one plus is enough(like the red in the picture) but it has to be centered in the middle of the list always.

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov Fixed according to your wish

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov I'm not going to spend more time on this, sorry. Look at the documentation of `siunitx` for avoiding exponential notation. The output of 18 times 12,7 seems right (except for the alignment, which I asked you hints for and you never said anything).

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov Please, remove the tick and I'll remove my answer, so you don't need to ask a duplicate question.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of hints, it's my fault because I want something very complicated with a lot of changes over the time.  I will remove my  last comments you did a great job.