# Array/tabular for long multiplication

Tags: arrays

In [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484728/adding-sign-betwen-lines-not-math-mode/484777?noredirect=1#comment1225917_484777) topic **@egreg helped me a lot** but there can be thousand of bugs in *horizontal long multiplication*.
I am a bit frustrated and can't make array like that: 
[image: array]

The red drawings are commas. I'm trying to use tabular it's not elegant at all.

Comment: Could you please add a code and a link to "the other topic"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you seek?  It uses `tabstackengine`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\tabbedShortunderstack[r]{
&&&&&&&\mathllap{30{,}24\cdot5{,}12}\\
\TABcline{1-8}
&&&&6&0&4&8\\
+\,&&&3&0&2&4&\\
&1&5&1&2&0&&\\
\TABcline{1-8}
&1&5&4&{,}8&3&&&
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

For cases where there are an even number of lines between the rules, one needs to raise the `+` half way, here with `\+` in lieu of `+`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\newcommand\+{\smash{\raisebox{.5\baselineskip}{$+$}}}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\tabbedShortunderstack[r]{
&&&&&&\mathllap{9{,}37\cdot1{,}90}\\
\TABcline{1-7}
&&&8&4&3&3\\
\+\,&&9&3&7&&\\
\TABcline{1-7}
&1&7&{,}8&0&&
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but result should be 154,2 :-)

Comment: Good but when I have only 2 numbers for addition like most of the time the `+` should be centered between them like this: https://imgur.com/a/yPurnum

Comment: @SimeonSimeonov Please see the supplement to my answer.